# How do I reliably convert /proc/pid/environ to arguments for the env command?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, dash

How do I reliable convert /proc/pid/environ to argument for the env command?

- `IFS=$'\n' ; env -i $(xargs -0n1 -a /proc/$$/environ)` only works when all environment variables do not have the newline character.
- `IFS=$'\0'`is not working in bash and dash.

Is there any other available way (included any other shell way)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash, you can create an array from entries in the `environ` file, and use the array elements as arguments to `env`:

```
mapfile -d '' envs < /proc/$$/environ
env -i "${envs[@]}" ...
```

It seems to work fine with newlines:

```
$ foo=$'a\nb' bash
$ mapfile -d '' envs < /proc/$$/environ
$ printf '|%s|\n' "${envs[@]}"
|foo=a
b|
|LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8|
|SSH_CONNECTION=127.0.0.1 33066 127.0.0.1 22|
...
```